# Logging in Designated Log in EventLog using NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, nlog

In my project (ASP.NET C# class library project) , we are using NLog.dll (v 4.0.0.0) to log exceptions to in eventviewer, in the below manner.

```
private readonly NLog.Logger _logger;
_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
_logger.Error(someText, someArgs);
```

Please find the NLog configurations used as below :

```
<target xsi:type="EventLog"
      name="eventlog"
      layout="${message}"
      machineName="."
      source="NLogLogger"
      log="Application" />
```

It works fine and logs messages in the Application log inside “Windows Logs”.
However, we require the logging to be performed in a separately designated log (custom log, specific for my application) .

We specified the name of the designated log in the config like below.

```
<target xsi:type="EventLog"
      name="eventlog"
      layout="${message}"
      machineName="."
      source="NLogLogger"
      log= “MyOwnCustomLog” />
```

But it still logs messages in the same Application log.

Please let me know how I can get it logged in the designated log.

Comment: what have you specified in the `rules` section of your configuration file?

Comment: I have written following rule
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="eventlog" />